# Why does .NET XmlDsigC14NTransform of XML subset not propagate namespaces correctly?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm unable to produce the output I want using the XmlDsigC14NTransform from .NET. I would like to perform C14N XML canonicalization of the `soapenv:Body` element.
I have the following sample XML

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://bankconnect.dk/schema/2014">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns:getCustomerStatement/>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

When I transform it using sc14n and the command `sc14n -s soapenv:Body sample.xml` i get the following output

```
<soapenv:Body xmlns:ns="http://bankconnect.dk/schema/2014" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <ns:getCustomerStatement></ns:getCustomerStatement>
  </soapenv:Body>
```

When I use the following C# code to do the transform

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography.Xml;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

namespace XmlBadC14n {
  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      var originalXmlContent = File.ReadAllText("sample.xml");
      XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument() {
        PreserveWhitespace = true
      };
      xDoc.LoadXml(originalXmlContent);
      var nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.NameTable);
      nsm.AddNamespace("soapenv", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
      var element = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//soapenv:Body", nsm);

      using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
        var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(ms);
        element.WriteTo(xmlWriter);
        xmlWriter.Flush();
        ms.Position = 0;
        var transform = new XmlDsigC14NTransform();
        transform.LoadInput(ms);
        var output = (transform.GetOutput(typeof(MemoryStream)) as MemoryStream).ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine($"{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(output)}");

      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following output

```
<soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <ns:getCustomerStatement xmlns:ns="http://bankconnect.dk/schema/2014"></ns:getCustomerStatement>
  </soapenv:Body>
```

The difference being where the `xmlns:ns` is placed. I would like it to be in the `soapenv:Body` element, otherwise the digest and signature will be different from what is expected. From what I can tell in the specification, canonicalizing a subset of a complete XML document means namespaces should be propagated down to the root element of the subset, which in this case should be `soapenv:Body` instead of `ns:getCustomerStatement`.